# Determining load voltage and current of a pump connected to long wires

Tags: voltage, power, current-measurement, long-distance

I'm trying to estimate the load voltage and current of a pump connected to a power supply with long wires. Here is a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1LwJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The power source voltage is V1 = 12 VDC.

The power source and the pump are separated by 6 meters, so approximately 12 meters of wires in total.
According to the cable datasheet, the resistance of this wire is 24.2 Ω/1000 ft, so total wire resistance = 0.9527 Ω.
I simplified the circuit by putting a resistor R with this value in series with the pump.

So from here everything seemed simple to me:

V1 = Vp + Vr

with:

Vr = R * I

and I is 7.5 A at 12 V according the pump datasheet, so:

Vr = 0.9527 * 7.5 ≃ 7.15V

(I know its an absurdly enormous voltage drop, but it's just an exercice).

So theoritically with all that information I can determine the pump voltage:

Vp = V1 - Vr
Vp = 12 - 7.15 = 4.95 V

But here my problems starts: at this specific voltage the pump is not drawing 7.5 A anymore.

So I ended up creating a graph of the pump's current consumption depending on voltage (with a simple bench test); here it is:

[image: Current consumption]

After that I started again all the above calculations but with I = 2.5 A to find that Vp is now ≃ 9.6 V, so I ≃ 5 A now, etc, etc.

Anyway, all of that to end up creating an Excel sheet to see to what value Vp in tending towards:

[image]

After a few iterations I can see that Up tends to about 8 V and the corresponding current is about 4.3 A.

The good news is that I made this circuit for real, and this is almost exactly what I measured. Up ≃ 7.9 V and I ≃ 4.3 A.

But all of that to come at this conclusion?

I'm sure there is a better way to calculate that without having to physically create a pump bench test and taking measurements.
And I'm sure I will feel really stupid as an electrical technician who can't remember their lessons (it's been a few years ago now haha).

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 4):

I think representing a pump as a resistor is going to have problems in the real world with many  kinds of pumps. It's a more problematic load than a simple resistive load. Many are going to have a surge when they start up and the current will vary through the cycle, so using a resistor may lead to incorrect conclusions. For example, compressors (a kind of pump) can stall if there is too much voltage drop, and that leads to an increase in power consumption and overheating of the motor. That's one reason why they caution you not to run certain appliances with an extension cord- because of the added resistance. Allowing significant voltage drop (like more than a few %) in the cable at the nominal/average current draw is more likely to cause that kind of failure. Of course if you know the pump does not draw power like that (maybe it has an inverter drive and power factor correction) you can call it closer. In the latter case, you might expect the current draw to go up as the inverter tries to compensate for the voltage drop (if it's not at 100%), which causes even more voltage drop, and heats the wires, causing more voltage drop.

So even if you look at the datasheet for the pump and it says it will operate with satisfactory performance for your application over a certain voltage range, and you use that current draw to calculate the minimum wire gauge for the wire run you might still have problems.

For practical advice, I would suggest referring to whatever documentation the pump manufacturer can supply. I've see recommendations for minimum wire gauge for given cable lengths for some products such as submersible pumps.

If you don't have access to that, maybe they've gone out of business or whatever, then experimentation (and then adding an adequate safety margin) may be your best bet after all.

In this particular case, and based on your measurements - which are probably average current- the pump seems to be adequately represented by 1.8Ω resistor (taken from the measurements at 12V and 9V) so you could predict the current as 12V/(1Ω+1.8Ω) = 4.3A. Which matches your measurements, but that's a very odd way to run a pump and may not be reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very clear and I know my setup isn't ideal. But the interesting point to me here is to understand how to calculate and predict the voltage drop. For this situation the resistor approximation is the simplest way to go, but I would like to know how to calculate it if the load isn't just a restive load.

Comment: If sufficient information is provided then you can calculate it (though note that in the example above there may even be multiple currents for one voltage, stalled and non-stalled) so the value depends on the past (a form of hysteresis). If there is no information provided, then you have to characterize the part yourself just as you did, and in a real design you'd want to add a safety margin because of variables such as temperature and unit-to-unit variations. All that requires time, money and skill, which is one reason why designers really don't like to deal with poorly specified components.